# join two consecutive list elements

Tags: python, list

i have a list `names` that looks like this

```
names = ['Peter Orson', 'Marc Johnson', 'Peter', 'Johnson']
```

i want to join **two specific elements** of that list.

```
desired_names = ['Peter Orson', 'Marc Johnson', 'Peter Johnson']
```

caveat:

1. i cannot use index
2. i need to target only these two individual elements even though other elements share some parts  (e.g. same first name)

code:

```
regex = re.compile(r'/^Peter$/)
for i in names:
    if regex:
        i = ' '.join(map(str, regex)) # join with next list element into one string
```

I think i have the right approach to my problem but i dont know how to join and replace the matched string elements

Comment: Do you mean you want to use a regex to match `Peter` or `Johnson` and the next word if you join the `names` with a space? Or what is the rule for a regex? What logic are you trying to implement?

Comment: Yes, more precicely i only want to match `/^Peter$/` and join it with the next list element (`'Johnson'`). I know for sure, that `Johnson` is the next list element after `Peter`.

Comment: You don't need a regex.  "if names[i] == "Peter":` is a much better solution.  Heck, you can even find it directly using `idx = names.index('Peter')`

Comment: thanks, i feel very incompetent now :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you don't need the regex to do that:

```py
names = [
    "Peter Orson",
    "Marc Johnson",
    "Peter",
    "Johnson",
]

idx = names.index("Peter")
names[idx] = names.pop(idx) + " " + names[idx]
print(names)
```

Prints:

```py
['Peter Orson', 'Marc Johnson', 'Peter Johnson']
```

---

If you aren't sure if `"Peter"` is in the list, you can check before:

```py
if "Peter" in names:
    idx = names.index("Peter")
    names[idx] = names.pop(idx) + " " + names[idx]
```